# Error when importing csv files into panda data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am importing csv files with this code:

```
# import necessary libraries
from typing import Counter
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
 
# in the folder
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

# Delete CSV file 
# first check whether file exists or not
# calling remove method to delete the csv file
# in remove method you need to pass file name and type

del_file = path+"\\"+'file_name.csv'

## If file exists, delete it ##
if os.path.isfile(del_file):
    os.remove(del_file)
    print("File deleted")
else:    ## Show an error ##
    print("File not found: " +del_file)

# use glob to get all the csv files
csv_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))
df_list= list()

#format columns
dict_conv={'line_item': lambda x: str(x),
           'column_item': lambda x: str(x)}

# loop over the list of csv files
for f in csv_files:     
    # read the csv file
    df = pd.read_csv(f, sep=";", converters = dict_conv)
    df_list.append(df)
    #print the location and filename
    print('Location:', f)
    print('File Name:', f.split("\\")[-1])

#add data frames to a list 
RLI_combined = pd.concat(df_list, axis=0)
```

But I get this error when 'file_name.csv' is not in the directory:

```
File not found: d:\Python\Pandas concat csv files\v_1\file_name.csv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Python\Pandas concat csv files\v_1\from pathlib import Path.py", line 37, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv(f, sep=";", converters = dict_conv)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 586, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 482, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 811, in __init__
    self._engine = self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 1040, in _make_engine      
    return mapping[engine](self.f, **self.options)  # type: ignore[call-arg]
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\c_parser_wrapper.py", line 69, in __init__   
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(self.handles.handle, **kwds)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 542, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 642, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._get_header
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 843, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1917, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe5 in position 534: invalid continuation byte
```

What is happening here the script is sopposed to delete the file so it wont be placed in the data frame with the other csv files.
I hope you can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing `latin1` in the encoding parameter, has helped me when it comes to special characters. Kindly try:

```
df = pd.read_csv(f, sep=";", converters = dict_conv,encoding='latin1')
```

Comment: Thank @Celius Stingher you this solved the issue, what happens when you do this?

Comment: Python comes with different codecs built-in and the way files are encoded might differ with the the default configuration (utf-8). In the case of using special characters from different languages you might run into encoding compatibility issues and need to manually specify which encoding to use. Better information regarding codecs can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings

Comment: As a follow up, I have defaulted to `latin1` because it was most likely the most inclusive one I've come across for western languages. It doesn't mean it's necessarily the best one.